# How to unregister a testcase and how to register a particular test case into Gtest

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, googletest, googlemock

in gtets as we know, the moment control finds `TEST` or `TEST_F` function, it `registers` the `test cases` into `gtest`. But according to my requirement, after gtest registers all the testcases 
I need to search whether the `testcasename` is there in the list or not?
If the `tesetcasename` is there then I need to unregister all the test cases and register only
the found `testcasename`.
How to do that???
Suppose

```
TEST_F(testcasename, testname){}
TEST_F(testcasename1, testname1){}
TEST_F(testcasename3, testname3){}
..
..
TEST_F(testcasenameN, testnameN){}
```

Suppose I am searching for `"testcasename3"` in the `registered testcasename`. and it's available.
Now I want gtest to execute only the found testcase not all...

How to do that?

Any answer is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the command line as described in the advanced guide, so

```
./foo_test --gtest_filter=testcasename3.*
```

would only run `testcasename3` and all its tests. The commandline syntax is extensive, tests and be included and excluded using wildcards. See the [advanced documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#running-test-programs-advanced-options) for more information

Comment: To my requirement I should not use filter where I have to unregister then register the test cases.

Comment: I don't think this can be done without sloshing through the internals, afaik, google turns each case/test pair into a class, that class only gets instantiated when executed, i.e. if you filter some, the cases that where filtered out are registered in a sense that gtest knows how to instantiate the class that would run that case. But that instantiation only happens for the case/test pairs that match the filter criteria

Comment: Finally decided to use for `filter`. Thanks A Lot